# No neutral wire when hanging light?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have been trying to hang a living room light. There is ONLY a black (hot) wire coming from the box in the ceiling. The chandelier I'm trying to hang has a copper (ground) wire and TWO other wire (both wrapped brown). I'm used to have a black and white wire coming from the box in the ceiling and a black and white from the light fixture as well.

Comment: You will need the white, neutral, wire.  Is there a white wire in the switch  box?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the ceiling box?

Comment: So what happened to the white wire 

Comment: I'll try to get a picture! And good question... the old chandelier was up there and worked without the white one so I have no idea wtf is going on haha